# Third process "wc" won't work

Tags: c, fork

I'm currently having a problem with the third process because it wont work every time when  I run the program. And suggestions with the `exit()` part because is printing multiple child process! Any suggestions?

I would really APPRECIATE it a lot!

```
main(){
    pid_t son;
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        switch (i){
            case 0:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    execlp("/bin/cat", "cat", "wctrial.txt", NULL);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Child process completed!");
                //exit(0);
                }
            case 1:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    execlp("/bin/mkdir", "mkdir", "mydirectory", NULL);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Child process completed!");
                //exit(0);
                }
            case 2:
            son = fork();
                if (son<0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed!");
                    //exit(-1);
                }else if (son == 0){
                    execlp("/bin/wc","wc","wctrial.txt", NULL);
                }else{
                wait(NULL);
                printf("Child process completed!");
                //exit(0);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What is not working?

Comment: "it won't work" doesn't help much. How does it fail? What is the actual output and what is the expected output?

Comment: RTFM on execlp: "The list of arguments must be terminated  by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char \*) NULL." You MUST cast NULL to a char\*; there are plenty of OSs (including some linux, Darwin) where the code *will* fail.

Comment: the third process doesn't display the word count of the text...

Answer (score 2):

At least I don't see the `break` at the end of the each `case`.

In the case of `0` the program will run through all of your `case`s.

Comment: Agreed, but is it really necessary in context of `exec`?

Comment: @bash.d There are calls to `fork` as well, and only the child processes call `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `break` is the problem that if case 1 execute then 2,3 also will.(*but this is not problem that `wc` not working*)

> **Why `wc` is not working ?**

Because of path of `wc` command!

In your system path for wc  may not is: `"/bin/wc"`

Search tha path of `wc` command in your system like:

```
:~$ whereis wc
wc: /usr/bin/wc
```

and change

```
 execlp("/bin/wc","wc","wctrial.txt", NULL);
           ^
```

as

```
 execlp("/usr/bin/wc","wc","wctrial.txt", NULL);
          ^ 
          // actually not exactly this but one that appears in your system.
```

Give it a try!!

Comment: isn't it the same with "../bin/wc"?

Comment: @Dale what `whereis wc` result in your system tell me? I guess that is the error..it happens too may time with me and `"/usr/bin/wc"` `!=` `/bin/wc"`

Answer (score 0):

Below are my suggestion ,

> 1st) suggestion would be the clean-up of child process once it is
>   done,  as below,

```
 }else if (son == 0){
        execlp("/bin/mkdir", "mkdir", "mydirectory", NULL);
        _exit(0);
 }
```

> 2nd) do break after each switch statement
>
> 3rd) and also validate the path of executable by using "whereis"
>   command before feeding into execlp routine.